# get columns from numpy array in specific format given column indices

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a numpy array like this:

```
import numpy as np

# Create a NumPy array
array_data = np.array([[1, 2, 3],
                       [4, 5, 6],
                       [7, 8, 9]])
```

and yes I can get the 2nd column like this:

```
column_index = 1
selected_column = array_data[:,1]
print(selected_column)
```

giving:

```
[2 5 8]
```

I need it like this though:

```
[[2]
 [5]
 [8]]
```

which I can get using:

```
selected_column = array_data[:, column_index:column_index+1]
print(selected_column)
```

Now you wonder, why ask this question. Well I would like to actually provide several column indices (coming from a pandas data frame with provided column names) whilst still getting the array like the last output.

```
selected_column = array_data[:, column_index:column_index+1]
```

Comment: it's better to post that dataframe with column names and the expected output from it

Comment: For your first example, another solution is `array_data[:, (1,)]`, which would also give you [[2], [5], [8]]. Note the different effect that the tuple `(1,)` has compared to the scalar `1`. So if you want multiple columns, you can adapt that by using a tuple containing all your column indices.

Comment: Indexing a n-d array with a scalar "removes" that dimension.  So your column selection is a 1d array.  In `pandas` selecting a `column` returns a `Series`, which is also 1d, but displayed as a column.  Anyways there are multiple ways of getting the desire (n,1) shaped column array - reshaping the 1d, indexing with an list/array, `[1]` or with a slice as you do.

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest - yes you are right - in hindsight that would have been better ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use reshape?

```
array_data[:, column_index].reshape(-1, 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```py
selected_column_vector = array_data[:, [1]]
```

Which can be used to fetch several columns too:

```py
column_index = 1
result = array_data[:, [column_index, column_index + 1]]
```